# Can't configure JDBC connection to SQL Server

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports

I have been struggling to connect jasper reports to my SQL Server 2008.

I've tried a few different drivers, and it appears I'm able to connect, but it always complains about my user ID. I know I can connect with these credentials as I use SSMS all the time with them. I've tried doing a few things, like adding our domain to the server in the connection string, or prefixing my user id with domain\username. It still tells me "login failed for user 'me'"

I've tried `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver` and `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

I made sure that the proper driver is set in the classpath. (if they weren't we wouldn't see it even connect, let alone tell me my user failed)

Is there a setting that I have to have enabled on my SQL Server to allow JDBC connections?

Any ideas?

**net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver**
Here's the connection string `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://servername/database`

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'me'.
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:130)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:128)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:162)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:59)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'me'.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:632)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:168)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:128)
... 4 more
```

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**
Connection string: `jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;databaseName=database`

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'me'. ClientConnectionId:1a482dde-a84f-4e8b-9571-cb5a9dcfcfc9
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:130)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:128)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:162)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:59)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'me'. ClientConnectionId:1a482dde-a84f-4e8b-9571-cb5a9dcfcfc9
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:168)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:128)
    ... 4 more
```

I've added this video to show the issue. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPfJXYo6q9U

Comment: Could you please upload more code ?

Comment: That is all that is provided in the error. I'll add my connection string, but that's all there is to it. There's no source code, I'm using Jasper Studio 6.2

Comment: How about port number ?

Comment: I have stuff like this: jdbc:sqlserver://MyServer;instanceName=TheInstance;databaseName=TheDatabase; using sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: Peter, what driver are you using with the above?

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (use @Petter was just lucky to see your comment)

Comment: Going by the error _"Login failed for user 'me'."_ you are using a user that does not exist, or you are using the wrong password, or you are trying to login with a domain user, while username + password is only for SQL server users. To login with a domain user you need to use `integratedSecurity=true` and have the right DLL on the library path.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the user definitely exists, I use it with SSMS all the time. It's tied to my AD account. As you suggested, I think you're on to something... I think I may need to alter the default JDBC string to include an integrated security true string. `jdbc:sqlserver://servername:1433;databaseName=databasename` that is my connection string right now, where would you add the integrated security part? I tried adding it at the end and got a "this driver is not configured for integrated auth" error :(

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx under _"Connecting with Integrated Authentication On Windows"_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I made a vodeo to show the strange behavior I get. https://youtu.be/nPfJXYo6q9U This video shows the strange behaviour while I try to create a data source, then a report. 
You'll see at 1:12 the new data source connection is successful. But when I try to create a new report and use that data source, it then complains that it's not set up to use integrated security... then why did it connect in the first place?  I have added the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file to every JRE and JDK BIN and LIB folder on my computer to be safe. I have no idea what else I can do...